# Ruby passing blocks to blocks

Tags: ruby, closures

```
(1..5).each do|x| puts yield(x) end do |x| return x*2 end
```

In my head this would loop 1 through 5 call the first block that would yield to the second block and put 2,4,6,8,10

Why does this not work and whats the easiest way to write this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield` works within the methods. Quote from "Programming Ruby":

> Within the method, the block may be invoked, almost as if it were a
>   method itself, using the yield statement.

So, if you want to make this code working, you can change it to something like this:

```
def f(n)
  (1..n).each do |x|
    puts yield(x)
  end
end

f(5) do |x|
  x * 2
end
```

If you don't want to define method you should put block into the variable and then use it:

```
b = Proc.new{|x| x *2 }

(1..5).each do |x|
  puts b.call(x)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to write this:

```
(1..5).each { |x| puts x*2 }
```